# How Can I get data from cloud firestore without using .then()

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data without using promise shown in here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

In cloud function console, I am not getting the data instantly.

```
docRef.get().then(doc => {
        console.log("In Then");
        console.log('Authorized User Data From Function:', doc.data());
        result = doc.data();
        // if (!doc.exists) {
        //   console.log('No such document!');
        // } else {
        //   console.log('Payment Request Data:', doc.data());
        // }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("In Catch");
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
        return false;
    });

// I don't want to use this. This is taking time to complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Cloud Firestore asynchronously. There is no way to get the data from a cloud based database instantly. You will have to get used to working with such asynchronous API if you want to be able to use most modern web APIs.

The closest you can get to not having a `then()` is by using `async`/`await` on a modern Node.js environment. With `async`/`await` the above code would ready like this:

```
doc = await docRef.get();
console.log('Authorized User Data From Function:', doc.data());
result = doc.data();
```

Keep in mind though: while this may read more natural at first, under the hood it is still doing the exact same thing.